# How are photons that are quantumly entangled connected

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

i know that they arn't in the normal sence connected but how is it that when one particle is observed spinning up the other one "starts" spinning down.
It can't have always been spinning down.

Comment: *It can't have always been spinning down.* Do you know what quantum superposition is?